# How to limit query depth in strawberry-graphql (Django implementation)?

Tags: django, graphql, depth

I have a nested structure in my strawberry-graphql schema resolver implementation. Any suggestions on how I can limit query depth in strawberry-graphql (Django implementation)?

Answer (score 1):

This is will soon be a feature in Strawberry: https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry/pull/1021

You'll be able to define a validator that you can pass to the `execute` command:

```python
import strawberry
from strawberry.schema import default_validation_rules
from strawberry.tools import depth_limit_validator
# Add the depth limit validator to the list of default validation rules
validation_rules = (
  default_validation_rules + [depth_limit_validator(3)]
)
# assuming you already have a schema
result = schema.execute_sync(
    """
    query MyQuery {
      user {
        pets {
          owner {
            pets {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    """,
    validation_rules=validation_rules,
  )
)
assert len(result.errors) == 1
assert result.errors[0].message == "'MyQuery' exceeds maximum operation depth of 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

from the creator and the maintainer example from [here](https://github.com/patrick91/strawberry-workshop/blob/complete-djangocon/api/schema.py) you can use

```
schema = strawberry.Schema(
    query=Query,
    mutation=Mutation,
    extensions=[
        # 8 is the maximum depth in this case
        QueryDepthLimiter(8),
    ],
)
```